# JQUERY won't work on local machine

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying JQUERY on my machine, but for some reason, nothing seems to work.   Here's the test file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/css" src="jquery.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("p").mouseover(function () {
      $(this).css("color","black");
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
$("body").css("background-color","black");
$("body").css("color","white");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a test</h1>
<p>Roll over me!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing in there works. Also, if anybody wants to know, accessing through my domain and through the local both don't work. I'm really confused, because I copied most of that code off the internet, just in case there was something wrong with my typing.

For some reason, firefox is throwing this error:

Code: Evaluate
$ is not defined
http://hussain.mooo.com/jq.html
Line: 6
$ is not defined
http://hussain.mooo.com/jq.html
Line: 6

New code (moved the p onmouseover handeler)

```
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/css">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").mouseover(function () {
      $(this).css("color","black");
    });
$("body").css("background-color","black");
$("body").css("color","white");
});
</script>
```

Comment: is jquery.js actually present?

Comment: Please revert your question, otherwise this defeats the purpose of asking and the whole SO model.

Comment: I had the same difficulty in my jquery code, till I found the solution to the problem in this forum's question : [Jquery codes doesn't work if I'm using a local jquery.js file, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926701/jquery-codes-doesnt-work-if-im-using-a-local-jquery-js-file-why?rq=1)
It's an encoding problem, which disappears when you use the charset="UTF-8" attribute in the script tag of the .js .For details, visit the question mentioned above.

Answer (score 22):

Specify correct type for javascript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

**Update**

You're currently using `type="text/css"` as content type for javascript file which is incorrect. Try to copy above code into your script.

**Screenshot**

*removed dead ImageShack link*

Comment: the best solutions are oftentimes the most obvious ones... haha

Comment: Or just remove it.  The "type" attribute is unnecessary (and potentially dangerous, it seems) for script tags.

Comment: You got **way** too much upvotes, regardless a +1 for the screenshot :)

Answer (score 0):

Install [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and see what it tells you in the Console tab.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the attachment of the mouseover handler into $(document).ready(...) because the paragraph won't necessarily exist until the document is ready and so no handler can be attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of jQuery "jquery-1.3.2.min.js" and link the file correctly. and try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("p").mouseover(function () {
      $(this).css("color","black");
    });

    $("body").css("background-color","black");
    $("body").css("color","white");
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have the latest version installed (I just redownloaded it), still nothing.

Comment: Install firefox firebug and enable the console and refresh the page, see what it tells you: 1. if you cant see the jquery.js then you need to link it properly, if you cant see anything then your java script is disabled... try checking that.