# jQuery code doesn't work if I'm using a local jquery.js file, why?

Tags: jquery, file, local

Let's say this my page for example ..

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      });
    </script>
    <div id="div1"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you see I'm using a local jQuery file (`jquery.js`) so every time I write jQuery code it doesn't work knowing that both of my page and `jquery.js` in same level ..

But when I'm using a jQuery file online, like this for example

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

everything works fine..

Also I tried to put `<script></script>` in the `<head>` but nothing works

P.s. I downloaded the same file I'm using online and using it locally.

Comment: Is the local jQuery file actually getting loaded? What happens if you load it directly in your browser? What does Firebug's "Net" tab have to say about it?

Comment: Are you sure the jquery.js filename is correct?

Comment: @Pekka this is what firebug says about it http://cl.ly/6YUl

Comment: @Damien yes I'm sure, I just copied the file name and put it my code

Comment: Why is it in dropbox? Whats the URL for your page?

Comment: @Damien here's the local file http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5307742/web/demo_local/page.html and here's the file http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5307742/web/demo_online/page.html

Comment: @Sam: Got it. It's an encoding problem. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Sam , can you create a brand new page and give a try , looks like something got corrupt in the file type while saving the file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an encoding problem. Your `page.html` file is in UTF-16 (although it contains an erroneous `meta` tag saying that it's using UTF-8), but the `jquery.js` file isn't (it's either in ASCII, Windows-1252/ISO-8859-1, or UTF-8 — doesn't really matter which, it sticks to the characters all of them have in common).

I suggest correcting the encoding of `page.html` (making it actually UTF-8). That will probably clear it up. But if not, or if you really want UTF-16 (e.g., you're doing a page mostly in non-Western script) you can use the [`charset` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-charset) on the `script` element to tell the browser what to expect when fetching the script.

Here's how I got there: When I visit [the link you posted](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5307742/web/demo_local/page.html), I get an "illegal token" error in `jquery.js` in the console (on Chrome and in Firebug) and the `jquery.js` file content shown is garbled, showing mostly in an east asian character set. If I request the resource directly, I don't have that problem. That immediately made me think "encoding problem" and go look at `page.html`. A quick glance revealed it to be in UTF-16. Double-checked that the `jquery.js` file wasn't also in UTF-16 (it could be, though I would never encode JavaScript that way, it would be very wasteful) and found it to be in an ASCII-compatible encoding (e.g., not UTF-16).

If you're not 100% certain you understand what I'm saying about `page.html` being in UTF-16 but `jquery.js` being in UTF-8 or similar, I'd recommend reading [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!*)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky and also the various FAQs on unicode.org, in particular [the main one](http://www.unicode.org/faq/basic_q.html) and [the one discussing the various UTFs and the BOM](http://www.unicode.org/faq//utf_bom.html).

Comment: okay T.J. `charset="UTF-8"` solved the problem .. but why could that happened, I always doing that without using the charset

Comment: @Sam: The reason is that your `page.html` file is in UTF-16 (even though it says it's in UTF-8). The browser will assume the same encoding for things that page links to unless it's told otherwise; Dropbox isn't giving back any encoding headers on the request for `jquery.js` at all. Although adding `charset` works, I suspect the real problem is that you've inadvertently used UTF-16 on your `page.html` file. Do you **really** mean to be using UTF-16?

Comment: Now I really understand it .. looks it was a problem with my text editor http://cl.ly/6ZMr and I change it to http://cl.ly/6Y5e so it's working now even without **charset**, thant's T.J. for clearing things up :)

Comment: @Sam: Good deal, glad that helped!

Answer (score 2):

The browser should not care whether the file is local [local to the *webserver*, presumably...?].

Something is wrong with the copy of the file that you have locally. Ensure that the path is correct and use Firebug to see what happened to its loading.

---

**Edit** For your `demo_local`, my Firebug installation complains of foreign characters in the jquery.js file. When I look on the Script tab, it appears to be in Unicode but is served as ASCII.

Comment: I'm pretty sure about file name and this what firebug says http://cl.ly/6YUl and I'm using the same file which I downloaded from the same URL in my post

Comment: @Sam: Then the first part of Tomalek's statement is the relevant one: *"Something is wrong with the copy of the file that you have locally."*

Comment: @Tomalak: "T.J." ;-) (Hopefully that's not the *second* time I've spelled your name wrong, I totally see "Tomalek" even though it clearly has an "a" there.)

Comment: @Tomalak That's really weird, I just download the file from here `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` then rename it to jquery.js and put it beside my page without any modifies

Comment: Same in Chrome debugger ... I see a lot of strange characters. perhaps adding a [`Content-Type:application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8`](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset) header will work.

Answer (score 0):

sam

You have some wierd code in that jquery.

looks like jquery.js locally is wrong

please download it from here

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js

can you try the following

a standard doc type

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html lang="en">
```

and change script to

```
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
```

Comment: here it is http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5307742/web/demo_downloaded/page.html .. SAME PROBLEM

Comment: @sam , can you please try the changes i suggested.

Comment: @same , might be something wrong with the way you are downloading the jquery file on your machine.

Comment: @kobe: Actually, the `jquery.js` file is just fine. (Grab it directly rather than via `page.html` to see.) The reason it looks garbled when loaded in `page.html` is an encoding problem, see my answer for details.

Comment: @kobe added http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5307742/web/demo_1_6_changes/page.html still getting illegal characters

Comment: @T.j crowder , thats great catch then , i was also suspecting something in that line only as i always create html files through visual studio i never ran across this problem

Comment: @sam , looks like T.J crowder found the issue , did you look at it.

Comment: @kobe: Re *"can you try...a standard doc type"* He **is** using [a standard DOCTYPE: HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-doctype).

Answer (score -2):

I can see you are using dropbox to host your files, which automatically means you cannot make local reference to your files. Try including the full dropbox link and see if it works

Comment: Why? If he's requesting `page.html` from a path on Dropbox (as he appears to be), the path to `jquery.js` will be on Dropbox as well.

Comment: The screenshot posted by the OP indicates a successful download of both resources from Dropbox, I believe..?

Comment: I'm working locally but I just uploaded to dropbox to see what's gonna happens and unfortunately the same problem

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, you are right. Could this be a browser issue? @Sam what browser have you tested this on?

Comment: @boug firefox and safari .. btw just to make things clear I mean by locally just loading the file beside my page.html so it doesn't matter if it's on dropbox or not

Comment: @Sam I now understand that. what i would normally do in this case is to type the full path of the jquery.js into my browser and see if it loads up. I hope doing this points you to the right direction

Comment: @Sam I think @T.J Crowder has got something interesting here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926701/jquery-codes-doesnt-work-if-im-using-a-local-jquery-js-file-why/5926793#5926793