# Local jQuery.js file not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had downloaded jQuery.js file from jQuery.com .I have saved this file in 3 places, including JRE/Lib and desktop (where my HTML file which calls it is), to be sure that the jQuery.js file is found. I reference this js file as :

```
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#clas").click(function(){
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="clas"> Hello</p>
    <p>Hi</p>
</body>
```

When I ran this HTML file on Mozilla browser, I expected 'Hello' to vanish when I clicked on it, but it did not. It remained as solid as ever.
But when I used a jQuery CDN:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js">
```

And when I used an online HTML editor called Tryit Editor v1.5, it worked correctly!
It seems only the local jQuery.js is not doing its part. The JavaScript works fine, only the $() part doesn't. I'm using jdk1.6. I wonder why this snag has occurred. How to resolve it? Help.

Comment: What do you see in the developer tools?

Comment: Are you sure of the name "jquery.js" (ie not "jQuery.js" if you're on windows, nor "jquery.min.js") ?

Comment: Add alert($); before running your code to make sure it is defined... If it isn't then your path needs adjusting.

Comment: there is a lot of difference between 'jquery.js' and '/jquery.js'

Comment: I get the output as:       Hello    Hi                                                                     But the Hello does not disappear on clicking, as it should. It is as though the code lines starting with $(   have not been executed. The local jquery.js does not work, with/without the '/' before the jquery.js. And I have saved the jquery script as jquery.js in the same folder (desktop) as the html file.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks! I found the solution to this problem, from a similar question posted in this forum, asked a year ago. Here is the link:

[jQuery code doesn't work if I'm using a local jquery.js file, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926701/jquery-codes-doesnt-work-if-im-using-a-local-jquery-js-file-why?rq=1)

The problem seems to have been incompatible encoding of the html and the js files. So I added the charset attribute to script tag of js. And the problem and 'Hello' both vanished at a click!

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me. Please check the below code, I have just modified the location of the jquery.js file where mine is stored in a different location.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<%--<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>--%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#clas").click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="clas">Hello</p>
<p>Hi</p>
</body>

</html>
```

I assume the location of your js is not correct. Are you using the same path of js where you have this "html" or jsp page? Or you have the js files in a separate folder?

Additionally, you can try alternate way as below:

```
$("#clas").live("click", function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks to all. The alternate way does work, as long as the jquery script called is from a cdn. The local jquery.js does not work, with/without the '/' before the jquery.js. And I have saved the jquery script as jquery.js in the same folder (desktop) as the html file, as already verified. A copy of this same jquery file is also there in jre/lib.