# Local jQuery file doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

My question is pretty much exactly like in [jQuery code doesn't work if I'm using a local jquery.js file, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926701/jquery-codes-doesnt-work-if-im-using-a-local-jquery-js-file-why?rq=1).

However, the solution given there, doesn't work for me.

I created a file with `UTF-8` encoding, but it will still not render correctly.

Using the external `jQuery` files work though.

Here is my MWE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script charset="utf-8" src="js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type=
    "text/javascript"></script>
    <script charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('div.ui-page').live("swipeleft", function() {
                var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
                if (nextpage.length > 0) {
                    $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, {
                        transition: "slide",
                        reverse: false
                    });
                }
             });
             $('div.ui-page').live("swiperight", function() {
                 var prevpage = $(this).prev('div[data-role="page"]');
                 if (prevpage.length > 0) {
                     $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {
                         transition: "slide",
                         reverse: true
                     });
                 }
             });
         });       
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h2 class="ui-title"><strong>Page one</strong></h2>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <strong>You are in page one.</strong>
        </div>

        <div data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed" data-role="footer">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><strong><a data-icon="home" href=
                    "index.html">Home</a></strong></li>

                    <li><strong><a data-icon="info" href=
                    "b.html">Info</a></strong></li>

                    <li><strong><a data-icon="gear" href=
                    "#">Settings</a></strong></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /navbar -->
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div>

    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h2 class="ui-title"><strong>Page two</strong></h2>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <strong>You are in page two.</strong>
        </div>

        <div data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed" data-role="footer">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><strong><a data-icon="home" href=
                    "index.html">Home</a></strong></li>

                    <li><strong><a data-icon="info" href=
                    "b.html">Info</a></strong></li>

                    <li><strong><a data-icon="gear" href=
                    "#">Settings</a></strong></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /navbar -->
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated in jQuery since v1.7, and has been removed in v1.9.

You should replace it with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

`.on` has 2 syntaxes for binding elements, whereas `.live` only had 1.

If the element exists at the time you are binding, you do it like this:

```
$('.element').on('click', function(){
  ...
});
```

You can even use the shorthand:

```
$('.element').click(function(){
  ...
});
```

If the element does not exist at the time, or new ones will be added (which is what `.live` was normally used for), you need to use "event delegation":

```
$(document).on('click', '.element', function(){
  ...
});
```

NOTE: You want to bind to the closest static element, not always `document`.

Comment: You were right. It does work, if I download jQuery 1.8.x. However, changing `.live` to `.on` doesn't work.

Comment: I guess, I will just have to stick with `jQuery 1.8.3`, since I don't really know if there are any other deprecated methods that I'm using.

Comment: You can include the [jQuery Migrate plugin](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin) to help with any other depreciated methods

Answer (score 4):

You must link to jQuery **first**. Above all of your other script files. So just move both jQuery files above your `cordova` and `index` .js files. Unless `cordova` and `index` does not contain jQuery techniques.

**Why?** You can't use jQuery before the browser interprets it.

Comment: How come it works with external links though? And nope. Didn't work for me.

Comment: Does your `cordova` or `index` files contain jQuery syntax/techniques?

Comment: I actually don't really know, but I think it has something to do with deprecated methods, as ROY Finley already stated.

Comment: likely because the external links are cached by visiting other sites with them, and therefore do not require load time. your local files need to be loaded.

Comment: Yes, you should *definitely* replace `.live()` with `.on()` As he stated, `.on()` has two methods for binding elements, `.live()` lacked one. And you can tell if it has jQuery syntax by checking  for the `$()` or `jQuery()` function. (Which are the same thing by the way). And if it is working by referencing externally, why don't you use it?

Comment: Because I'm writing a `PhoneGap` app, which is a pain in the a**, because there is a whitelist for every external link. Too troublesome to set those.

Comment: Ooh, okay. I see. Sorry I couldn't help!