# jQuery not running locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following links declared inside the head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/scripts.js"></script>
```

And the following code inside the scripts file:

```
$("#person").hover(function() { 
    // trigger the mouseover event
    $("#person-text span").addClass("important-info");
}, function() { 
    // trigger the mouseout event
    $("#person-text span").removeClass("important-info");
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

I have also tried adding the jQuery library through Google and Microsoft CDNs, but it didn't work as well.

Here is a screenshot from the console errors:
[image]

Comment: Any errors to report?

Comment: When trying to preview it on Chrome/Firefox it won't run.

Comment: Ok, are you looking at the console? Are there any errors?

Comment: Try to wrap whole code in document.ready function.

Comment: Do you have 404 error on the scripts.js file?

Comment: I added a screenshot with bracket's console

Comment: If the scripts are in the head, you'll need `$(document).ready` to be able to actually wait for the elements to be available.

Comment: @ChristosMaris No not your JSLint console, but the one build in your browser which will give you actual error messages

Comment: @ChristosMaris That image is not what we're looking for. In your browser, hit F12, a frame should open, and you should see a tab called "console". Click it and refresh your page. What do you see?

Comment: @RegencySoftware Why's that? jQuery works locally, provided that the file exists and is [encoded properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926701/jquery-code-doesnt-work-if-im-using-a-local-jquery-js-file-why#answer-5926793).

Comment: showdev, you are right, I must have been mixing that up with something else. I removed the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem few days back. I moved the custom script tag at the end of the HTML page and the code worked. It generally happens for the `$(document).ready()` function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/scripts.js"></script>
```

*Move the above line to the end of your Html page and that should work.*

Comment: What do you mean in the end of the HTML page? Where exactly?

Comment: First of all thanks so much, it worked. Second of all, does anyone know why?

Comment: whatever page u are using , HTML/PHP /ASPX . move this just before the </html> ending tag

Comment: @ChristosMaris I believe this answer is referring to [this strategy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105327/should-jquery-code-go-in-header-or-footer). Here's [another explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196702/where-to-place-javascript-in-a-html-file/23476758#23476758).

Comment: $(document).ready() function start executing after the page is Fully ready .After each and every single element load .

Answer (score 0):

try using `$(document).ready(function(){/*your code*/})` 
 and try to change  if your browser console showing  404 error for jQuery file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js
"></script>
```