# Local version of ReactJS not working on IE11, Edge, but remote version works

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, internet-explorer-11, local

UPDATE: It turns out this isn't just occurring for local ReactJS scripts, but also for any other local external scripts used on the webpage.

This issue only occurs in Internet Explorer 11 and Edge as far as I know. I'm not sure if it occurs in previous versions of Internet Explorer.

The following code is in the file called index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>   
<header><div id="header"></div></header>
<div id="scroller"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/react-dom.production.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/components/scroller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/widgets/header.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What happens is if I attempt to use a local version of React, I get the error

```
'React' is undefined
```

However, if I use a remote version of both copies of React it works fine. The same occurs with JQuery when I switch back to the remote version of React while trying to use the local version of JQuery. One solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926701/jquery-code-doesnt-work-if-im-using-a-local-jquery-js-file-why?rq=1) I tried was to make sure the files were using the same encoding for the files. I think I was able to make sure they all had the same encoding. However, this did not solve the issue.

What approaches can I go about solving this issue?

Comment: were your serving the `index.html` in a local http server, or were you opening it directly in browser as `file://`?

Comment: I was opening it directly in browser. Weirdly enough, some local scripts load, but the ReactJS just won't. I'm investigating further into the issue.

Comment: you should always use a simple apache/ other http local server to serve your html when developing in local. This can avoid many SOP and weird issue that won't happen after you go online.

Comment: The problem is I'm trying to serve the webpage via a webbrowser control in Visual Studio. However, because of this issue it won't load properly in the control. I was wondering if there would be a way to do this without resorting to having a server run in the background.